# Convert HTML to DOC in PHP

Tags: php, html, docx, doc

I am doing html to doc conversion by php header function. Converted file is saved in doc format. But when I edit and save this, it creates a folder with same name as doc file name, which contains three files (themedata.thmx, filelist.xml, colorschememapping.xml).
I am using following code for doc generation.

```
header("Cache-Control: ");
header("Pragma: ");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.doc"');
```

I want to convert it in pure doc file, please help to fix this problem.

I have tried many other plugins to convert HTML to DOC for example :-
1. Pandoc :- It is converting html to docx but not picking style and images from html file.
2. PHPWord :- I didn't find any option in PHPWord to convert fully styled HTML in to docx. It is   create docx by function (addTable, addCell) which I do not want.
3. htmltodocx.codeplex.com :- This plugin needs some specific style. It is not supporting all css.
4. unoconv :- Not found working.
5. Open office :- not found any functional command.

Comment: check this link https://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: @Anju - thanks for reply, I implemented htmltodocx.codeplex.com, but it need style in some array format and not supporting external css file, so this is not usable for me.

Comment: can any body suggest plugin like phpdocx. phpdocx is paid plugin and can not afford that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a file format simply by changing the file extension. Do you think you can convert a PDF to a movie by changing the file name from .pdf to .mp4? I hope not, because it doesn't make any sense.

What's happening is that you're telling the browser to save data of an HTML file with a .doc extension. When you double click that file to open it, Word opens (because it's associated with .doc extensions). Word is <strike>stupid</strike> <strike>misleading</strike> forgiving enough to recognise that the file does not actually contain Word DOC data, but HTML, and it converts it for you on the fly without telling you.
When you then save this file, it creates an actual DOC/DOCX file for it; but apparently that doesn't happen cleanly and the container is breaking apart.

What you're seeing it a misbehaviour in Microsoft Word (on several levels).

What you should be doing to begin with is create an actual Word document, e.g. using https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord.

Comment: (John Siracusa would go into a half hour fit ranting about file extensions at this point, and rightly so.)

Comment: thanks for reply, I want to create word file from fully styled HTML file. PHPWord does not have any option to create word from html (contain css and images) file.

Comment: Then find a library that can convert HTML to DOC. @Anju linked something in the comments. I cannot recommend any such library for you. The fact is, you need to produce an actual Word document one way or another, you can't be selling an HTML page as being .doc.